# resetting contents of NSMutableDictionary iVar

Tags: objective-c

I have an ivar I'll call dictionaryIvar, which is a mutable dictionary. Occasionally, its contents must be erased and reset with new contents. The contents are added over several iterations of indefinite quantity, hence why it is mutable.

Is it enough to "reset" or release the dictionary with:

```
 self.dictionaryIvar=nil;
```

And then in a different method, where needed, recreate the dictionary with:

```
 if(!self.dictionaryIvar){
 self.dictionaryIvar = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 }
```

Would this be acceptable, or would this leak the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your property is defined like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dictionaryIvar;
//...
@synthesize dictionaryIvar;
```

then the synthesized method would take care of releasing/retaining the dictionary objects.

```
self.dictionaryIvar = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

should thus be sufficient.

There's a distict difference between `self.dictionaryIvar` and `dictionaryIvar` wherein the former gets passed to a synthesized property method (`- (NSMutableDictionary *)dictionaryIvar;` and `- (void)setDictionaryIvar:(NSMutableDictionary *)aDictionary;` respectively) and `dictionaryIvar` simply accesses the variable.

Thus this would leak (and crash, both):

```
dictionaryIvar = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

while this wouldn't:

```
self.dictionaryIvar = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

---

But I'd (in most cases) really just go with this simple call:

```
[dictionaryIvar removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: `dictionary` is the class method and return an autorelease dictionary object and i suspect your statement `dictionaryIvar = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];` would cause a crash ..

Comment: @Jhaliya: Yes it would certainly crash (unless retained later on). In addition to leaking. Added a note to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that, why not just...

```
[dictionaryIvar removeAllObjects];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the contents of the dictionary, you could just replace it with the new dictionary. In one line:

`[dictionaryIvar setDictionary:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];`

That has the same effect of doing a `[dictionaryIvar removeAllObjects]` (which also sends a `release` to all objects contained in it), followed by adding the objects from the new dictionary (in your case, empty).

Also, by doing this you don't have to worry about your ivar's ownership and memory management issues if all you need to do is 'reset' the dictionary...

Answer (score 0):

It's not leaked as you are setting it with `nil` using `self.`, it will invoke the setter function for your `dictionaryIvar` and then will release the previously held object and assign `nil`.

I would prefer to call proper release on the `dictionaryIvar` variable.

```
  [dictionaryIvar release];
    dictionaryIvar = nil;
```

---

```
 if(!dictionaryIvar){
  dictionaryIvar = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] retain];
 }
```

Comment: Why should he use direct ivar access instead of just calling the setter?

Comment: @BJ Homer  : he has choices to go either way, but i prefer to use `self.propertyName` when you set your object with an already created object. like `self.propertyName = otherObject; `

Comment: That's fine, but if there's not a technical reason to use one over the other, then you might consider saying "I prefer to use _____" rather than "I would recommend _____", since the latter suggests that there's something wrong with what he's currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `@property` is set to `retain`, that should be fine. Using the dot notation (`self.dictionaryIvar`) automatically will release and retain your dictionary.

If you're just trying to clear the dictionary, though, it might be better to just call the dictionary's `-removeAllObjects` method:

`[self.dictionaryIvar removeAllObjects];`